# why the ^ symbol before the version is removed from package-lock.json

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I noticed that whenever I did `npm install --save`, my `package-lock.json` file got modified and the `^` symbol removed from the version.

For example,

```
"@babel/core": {
      "version": "7.7.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core/-/core-7.7.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-eeD7VEZKfhK1KUXGiyPFettgF3m513f8FoBSWiQ1xTvl1RAopLs42Wp9+Ze911I6H0N9lNqJMDgoZT7gHsipeQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@babel/code-frame": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/generator": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/helpers": "^7.7.0",
        "@babel/parser": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/template": "^7.7.0",
        "@babel/traverse": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/types": "^7.7.2",
        "convert-source-map": "^1.7.0",
        "debug": "^4.1.0",
        "json5": "^2.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "resolve": "^1.3.2",
        "semver": "^5.4.1",
        "source-map": "^0.5.0"
      }
```

changed to

```
"@babel/core": {
  "version": "7.7.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core/-/core-7.7.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-eeD7VEZKfhK1KUXGiyPFettgF3m513f8FoBSWiQ1xTvl1RAopLs42Wp9+Ze911I6H0N9lNqJMDgoZT7gHsipeQ==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "@babel/code-frame": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/generator": "7.7.2",
    "@babel/helpers": "7.7.0",
    "@babel/parser": "7.7.3",
    "@babel/template": "7.7.0",
    "@babel/traverse": "7.7.2",
    "@babel/types": "7.7.2",
    "convert-source-map": "1.7.0",
    "debug": "4.1.1",
    "json5": "2.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "resolve": "1.12.0",
    "semver": "5.7.1",
    "source-map": "0.5.7"
  }
```

I couldn't figure out the reason why it happened like this. Understand that by providing `--no-package-lock` flag would prevent modifying the existing `package-lock.json` file. But is there a way to retain the `^` while still keeping `package-lock.json` up-to-date?

Update:
My installed npm version is 5.6.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea behind `package-lock` file is that you will get a consistent installs no matter what environment you are installing it.
That means the installed versions must be **fixed to a specific version**.